# How to get the focused control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, focus, controls

How can I get a current focused control in WPF?

I found some solution for WinForms, but invoking WIN32 API function, didn't work in WPF?

Is there any way for doing it in WPF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I did

```
protected override void OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lostFocusControl = e.OldFocus;
}

private void PauseButton_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // invoke OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus handler
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it in XAML itself ?

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a late answer, but maybe people searching can find this helpful, I it found on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768(v=vs.110).aspx) in the "Navigating Focus Programmatically" section close to the bottom of the page:

```
UIElement elementWithFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
bool FocusedElement = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);
```

Found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8077580/14648642