# Finding out which control has focus

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Is there a way to figure out which control in my visualtree has focus?
This is mostly for debugging.

Comment: every control has a property HasFocus. You might use it in some way to figure your requirements

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like this

```
bool FocusedElement = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() == textBox;
```

Use [FocusManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager_members%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: The namespace is System.Windows.Input and is part of the PresentationCore.dll assembly.

Comment: as described here [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.focusmanager.getfocusedelement?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-input-focusmanager-getfocusedelement(system-windows-dependencyobject)) `FocusManager.GetFocusedElement()` requires the focus-scope as parameter. 
I used `FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this)`